# How to move the x-axis values and line points to the middle of two x-axis lines using chartjs?

Tags: javascript, html, css, chart.js

Using chartjs, I setup the following chart:

```
function myFunction(){
    var options = {
      type: 'line',
      data: {
        labels: ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"],
        datasets: [
            {
                data: [26, 26, 29, 28, 29],
                borderWidth: 2,
                fill: false,
                lineTension: 0
            },              
            {
                data: [26, 26, 33, 28, 30],
                borderWidth: 2,
                fill: false,
                lineTension: 0,
            }
        ]
      },
      options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
            display: false,
            ticks: {
                suggestedMin: 0,
                beginAtZero: true   
            }
          }]
        }
      }
    }

    var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
    new Chart(ctx, options);
}
```

[image: Current situation]

I want to move the points and the x-axis numbers to the right, sothat they are positioned between the axis lines. (like: 1 between 1 and 2; 2 between 2 and 3; etc.) See below:

[image: How I want it to be]

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Here is how you can do this :**

**ꜰɪʀꜱᴛ**

Set default chart type to **`bar`** , like so :

```
var options = {
      type: 'bar',
      data: {
         ...
```

**ꜱᴇᴄᴏɴᴅ**

Set first dataset­*'s* type to **`line`** , as such :

```
...
datasets: [{
         type: 'line',
         data: [26, 26, 29, 28, 29],
         ...
```

**ᴡᴏʀᴋɪɴɢ ᴇxᴀᴍᴘʟᴇ ⧩**

```js
function myFunction() {
   var options = {
      type: 'bar',
      data: {
         labels: ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"],
         datasets: [{
            type: 'line',
            data: [26, 26, 29, 28, 29],
            borderColor: 'rgba(0, 119, 220, 1)',
            borderWidth: 2,
            fill: false,
            lineTension: 0
         }, {
            data: [26, 26, 33, 28, 30],
            borderWidth: 2
         }]
      },
      options: {
         scales: {
            yAxes: [{
               display: false,
               ticks: {
                  suggestedMin: 0,
                  beginAtZero: true
               }
            }]
         }
      }
   }

   var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
   new Chart(ctx, options);
}

myFunction();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.6.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="chartJSContainer"></canvas>
```

Comment: Great! Is it also possible to remove those bars?

Comment: You can hide them by setting the 'data' fields to '0'. Thanks!